# What does "obey/peithomenois" mean in "but obey unrighteousness" Romans 2:8?

Tags: romans

**Romans 2:8** ESV

> "but for those who are self-seeking and do not obey the truth, but **obey** unrighteousness, there will be wrath and fury." My emphasis. [obey/*peithomenois*]

Can one obey unless a command is given?

Does "unrighteousness" issue commands with authority?

How is unrighteousness "obeyed"?

**Romans 1:5**

> "through whom we have received grace and apostleship to bring about the **obedience** of faith for the sake of his name among all the nations." [obedience/*hypakoen*]

Why is "obey" from *peithomenois* in Romans 2:8 when "obedience" comes from "*hypakoen*" in Romans 1:5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[peithomenois](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/romans/2-8.htm) comes from

> **[peithó](https://biblehub.com/greek/3982.htm):** to persuade, to have confidence
> **Original Word:** πείθω
> **Part of Speech:** Verb
> **Transliteration:** peithó
> **Phonetic Spelling:** (pi'-tho)
> **Definition:** to persuade, to have confidence
> **Usage:** I persuade, urge.

**Romans 2:8 - Peithó (πείθω)**: This word carries the meaning of persuasion or urging someone to do something. In the context of Romans 2:8, where "peithomenois" is used, it suggests a persuasion or influence toward unrighteousness. Individuals are being swayed or convinced to follow a path of self-seeking behavior and disobedience to the truth.

Here's the thing, unrighteousness often operates through deception, offering false promises, distorted truths, or misleading ideologies that appeal to selfish desires and/or sinful inclinations. **Individuals may be *persuaded* by the allure of immediate gratification or temporary gain, even if it means compromising on what is moral.**

As we see indicated by the text, unrighteousness itself does not issue commands with authority, at least not in the same way that an authority figure might. Instead, **it refers to a pattern of behavior displayed by adherence to sinful actions.** Those who are self-seeking and do not adhere to the truth but instead follow unrighteousness are described as "obeying" unrighteousness in the sense that their actions align or conform to their sinful desires.

---

[hypakoēn](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/romans/1-5.htm) comes from

> **[hupakoé](https://biblehub.com/greek/5218.htm):** obedience
> **Original Word:** ὑπακοή, ῆς, ἡ
> **Part of Speech:** Noun, Feminine
> **Transliteration:** hupakoé
> **Phonetic Spelling:** (hoop-ak-o-ay')
> **Definition:** obedience
> **Usage:** obedience, submissiveness, compliance.

**Romans 1:5 - Hupakoé (ὑπακοή)**: This word refers more specifically to obedience, submissiveness, or compliance. In Romans 1:5, where "hypakoen" is used, it shows an obedience of faith. This is about a willing submission to God's will and commands. This stems from trust and confidence in Him.

---

**Conclusion:** The use of different Greek words for obedience, is that there is nuances of obedience. Romans 2:8, is on the negative obedience to unrighteousness, which stems from a rejection of the truth. Romans 1:5, is on the positive obedience of faith. This comes from a willing submissiveness to God.

Comment: Up-voted +1. Memorable phrase : _persuaded by allure_.